# Cython: wrap a string vector with PyArray_SimpleNewFromData

Tags: python, string, numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray

*[This question has been edited as the presented code contained issues not related to the actual problem]*

I have implemented a generic function that shall convert c++ pointers to numpy arrays:

```
cdef np.ndarray pointer_to_array(void *ptr, np.npy_intp N, int np_type):
    cdef np.ndarray arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, np_type, ptr)
    return arr
```

Here, `*ptr` is a pointer to the underlying data, `N` is the size of the array and `np_type` is the numpy code for the type. The function works well for types with fixed size such as double.

However, I would like to apply the function to some kind of string array (e.g. `dtype('<U10')`). So what I try is

```
# mymodule.pyx

cdef get_v():
    # `v` is a std::vector[std::string] defined in an 
    # external header file and is assumed to persist over the
    # lifetime of the module
    return pointer_to_array(v.data(), v.size(), np.NPY_STRING)
```

However, I obtain a `ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize`. This makes sense, since numpy needs to know the size of the string. How can I pass this information to `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`? Or is there another way to wrap c++ arrays of strings with numpy arrays?

---

Further code needed for the example

```
# mymodule.pxd

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string 

cdef extern from "mymodule_cpp.h":
    vector[string] v
```

```
# mymodule_cpp.h

#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector[std::string] v(10, "Hello.");
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I don't think it's hugely helpful to what you're actually asking. I don't think that a string Vector really matches the format that a Numpy array expects. It might be possible with an "indirect memoryview" (but I don't know the topic well enough to usefully demonstrate it myself)

Comment: As DavidW has pointed out, std::vector<std::string>  and numpy-arrays have different memory layouts, thus you won't be able to wrap std::vector<std::string> into a numpy array without copying the data. Numpy-arrays don't support indirect memory views, thus you would also not able to pay the lesser price of creating array of addresses and wrap it (at least if the resulting array should be a numpy array). There are two options: the memory layout in the C/C++-code matches the memory layout of the numpy-arrays or copying.

Comment: If I were doing this I'd probably write a `cdef class` with a `__len__` and a `__getitem__` method that returned a Numpy view of an individual string I think. But I don't know if that fits your use-case exacty

Comment: I think I will go for the conventional solution and write - as suggested - a `cdef class` that holds a reference to the vector and gets and sets the items as desired. What would be the advantage of returning a numpy view? At the end, I just need a convenient way to access and manipulate the elements of the vector. A numpy array seemed to be the way to go.

Comment: A Numpy view of each string is just a convenient way to access the data of the string. Since you already have a good way of creating it then it seems like a reasonable option

Comment: @DavidW If I want to crate a numpy view onto the string vector, do you know how I can do this? I thought `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` would be the way to do that.

Comment: No. I don't think you can create a Numpy view on a string vector